# A way to configure typescript type description window size in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get more descriptive info regarding a type?
There is this '... 5 more ...' I want to see the 5 more.. Does someone know if this is configurable via VSCode? I couldn't find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's configurable, but you should be able to `CMD-Click` (mac) or `CTRL-Click` (windows) on the type, and it should open the file where that is defined (even if it's in `node_modules`). Then you can browse the types yourself.

Comment: Yeah that I know, but sometimes I have complex types that includes more than just Pick,
I assumed there would be a way to configure the depth of the evaluation of TS in the vscode editor